# Error:(1772) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'padding'

Tags: android

I am getting the error in the title. Here is the error log:

[image]

Comment: One more volunteer needed to close this post...

Answer (score 0):

Line No `1771` in `styles.xml` change `padding` to `android:padding`

Comment: when im trying to change  & hen after when i am bulid apk  then again this error show  ....

Comment: @meetjanani close this values xml file, go to your app's values folder, open styles.xml, find and change  padding to android:padding. The file you uploaded as a picture, is existing in build folder, not real resource. You cannot make changes into this file.

Comment: @meetjanani `i cant change any kind of code (text) in XML file` Change job. Programming doesn't seem to fit you well.

Comment: NoNo  Now I Can Abel To Do Programming In  Well maner okey    & By dave My Error Was Gone     Thanks ..

Answer (score 0):

Always qualify system resources with android , you had `padding` WHICH is not recognized as being apart of the android schema definition in XML, therefore resource qualification such as height, width, id, padding  and margin requires the `android:resource-name` qualification.

Happy Coding:)

Comment: i cant change any kind of code (text) in XML file       i cant change any kind of code (text) in XML file       WHAT i do....  Plz Suggest me solution